# When using Rcpp, I get "error: no viable overloaded '='. How can I resolve this?

Tags: rcpp, armadillo, rcpparmadillo

I am using Rcpp, and I'm struggling to resolve the "error: no viable overloaded '='. I believe that I'm using the correct set-up, where I load the R package `mvtnorm`, which contains the `rmvnorm` function.

R script:

```
library(mvtnorm)
Rcpp::sourceCpp("algorithm.cpp")
```

algorithm.cpp:

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
#include <RcppArmadilloExtensions/sample.h>

using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace arma;

arma::colvec algorithm() {

Environment myEnv = Environment::global_env();
Rcpp::Function rmvnorm = myEnv["rmvnorm"];

int p = 3;
arma::colvec test = arma::zeros(p);
test = rmvnorm(1, arma::zeros(p), arma::eye(p, p));

return test;
}
```

Error from VSCode:

```
error: no viable overloaded '='
test = rmvnorm(1, arma::zeros(p), arma::eye(p, p));
```

Then, I get the aforementioned error. I am found numerous posts that describe the same error, but none of the proposed solutions seem applicable; moreover, this error appears to be thrown for many reasons.

I tried the code provided in my post. I also referenced [this article](https://www.positioniseverything.net/no-viable-overloaded/), which did not resolve my issue.

Comment: Please include the entire error message in your post. As a side note: C++ isn't a scripting language. You need to put the code within a scope i.e. a function body or `main()`. If this isn't the actual code you are having problems with then please provide a `minimal reproducible example`

Comment: @RonSnow: Can you tell us what you really want to do? I see a lot of strings pulled but no reason behind.  Why do you need RcppArmnadillo and its sampling extension when what you try next is to pluck a function from the R side into C++ and evaluate it.  Doing that may not be as easy as it looks as these calls conform to `SEXP in, SEXP out`.

Comment: I've actually managed to progress with the compilation and truly, there seems to be an issue between conversion from `SEXP` (or `SEXPREC*`) to `double`.

Comment: That is what Rcpp does for you if you have the patience to look into. At a minimum `Rcpp::as<double>(sexpVar)` and `Rcpp::wrap(doubleVar)` will convert from/to `SEXP` and `double`.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Truth be told, I'm trying to write a large MCMC function in Rcpp (right now, it's in R). This was the first error that I found, so I made a MWE to reflect this error. The header is borrowed from a peer of mine. I suppose I do not need the sample header file. Ultimately, I want to write a Rcpp file that is capable of using R functions that I wrote AND that are in packages.

Comment: @MilanŠ. I have found that error as well, but I'm not sure how to resolve it. Ultimately, I want to write a Rcpp file that is capable of using R functions that I wrote AND that are in packages.

Comment: Why do you think you need `rmvnorm` ? Are you aware of this (old, but valid !!) [RcppGallery post](https://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/simulate-multivariate-normal/) ? Not involving R (esp in loops) will likely be faster than calling it (repeatedly).

Comment: My hands are tied here unfortunately, I only have surface level knowledge of `Rcpp` and when debugging I rely mainly on my `cpp` knowledge. However Dirk is an expert in this area as he is one of the main contributors of `rcpp` - he will most likely help you.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Excellent point! That would be much quicker. I suppose I'm stubborn about this issue, but I do need to use R functions (such as dGenWish from the rwc R package) that do not have equivalents in Rcpp. For this specific case of a multivariate Gaussian, that's not an issue. However, this error persists for any attempt to call an R function from inside Rcpp that belongs to another package.

Comment: Maybe as a last side note from me, why not implement dGenWish yourself? I'll admit it's been a few years since I finished my studies of Mathematics so I am a little bit rusty, but looking at the [details of dGenWish](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rwc/versions/1.11/topics/dGenWish).  It doesn't look that hard to implement.

Comment: There is also a metric ton of prior art for MCMC with Rcpp as some of the MCMC folks were early adopters. You may find bits and pieces.  My recomendation would be to start small, get some first things sorted out and then slowly get more sophiticated. Good luck!

Comment: @MilanŠ. I suppose I could write the function myself, but I was really hoping there would be a convenient way to call R functions in Rcpp without getting these types of errors.

Comment: Libraries like `rcpp` aren't really easy to write, because they do most of the dirty work for you at the price of limiting it's use. If you take a look at how you could call `R` libraries from `C` you would understand how much is `Rcpp` trying to be convenient to the end-user.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I believe I see that you actually answered this, and I was mistaking your answer as a side comment. My apologies for overlooking that. I appreciate your help!

Comment: I think some  issues are trying to grab the package from the global environment rather than explicitley with `Rcpp::Environment myEnv("package:mvtnorm");`, and trying to put the results of `rmvnorm` into a `colvec`. If you return a `NumericMatrix` it seems to play nice e.g. `Rcpp::NumericMatrix test = rmvnorm(1, arma::zeros(p), arma::eye(p,p));`

Comment: ... and an after thought; you could of course use a `colvec` but owuld eed to coerce it via `arma::colvec test = Rcpp::as<arma::colvec>(rmvnorm(1, arma::zeros(p), arma::eye(p,p)));`